# How to find pattern

Tags: pandas

I look for a way to find a pattern in a string which starts with recurring numbers and is followd by random letters.

For Example Pandas Dataframe:

```
     Data
0    12ABC
1    23DHZ
2    12AGZ
3    67AVB
5    12AZT
6    67AGG
```

I already do know the pattern to look at:

```
 search = [12, 23, 67]
```

And I want to find and assign the data which starts with a number pattern to a specific number, that the result is:

```
     Data   NumberPattern
0    12ABC  0
1    23ABC  1
2    12ABC  0
3    67ABC  2
5    12ABC  0
6    67ABC  2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First add `^` t opattern for match start of string, get values by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created by `enumerate` ans converting to string:

```
search = [12, 23, 67]
pat = '|'.join(r"^{}".format(x) for x in search)

d = {str(v): k for k, v in enumerate(search)}
df['NumberPattern'] = df['Data'].str.extract('(' + pat + ')', expand=False).map(d)
print (df)
    Data  NumberPattern
0  12ABC              0
1  23DHZ              1
2  12AGZ              0
3  67AVB              2
5  12AZT              0
6  67AGG              2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to extract the leading numbers and then [GroupBy.ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) for getting the group numbers.

```
values = df.Data.str.extract('(^\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df['NumberPattern'] = values.groupby(values).ngroup()
```

Output

```
    Data  NumberPattern
0  12ABC              0
1  23DHZ              1
2  12AGZ              0
3  67AVB              2
5  12AZT              0
6  67AGG              2
```